# Giant (non-mech) battle machines endlessly re-fighting a stalemate

Tags: story-identification

The thing I remember most clearly about this story is an image of a giant land battle machine (with ant-sized soldiers giving a sense of scale) overrunning another very much like it.  Each of the machines is long, many-wheeled, with a pointed prow and a rounded hull.  Weapons look like a row of horns along their lengths.  The machine driving from the left of the image shows at least 4 or 5 wheels along its right (visible) side, with the impression of much more of the vehicle out of view.  It is riding up at an angle over the machine from the right, with the first pair of wheels in mid-air.

I'm not sure if this was a piece of cover art or interior art of a collection or magazine.

What I remember of the story is a protagonist (astronaut? explorer?) who discovers two countries/societies endlessly locked in a conflict that neither side has been able to win.  They have similar size, technology and resources, and they repeatedly fight over the same ruined battleground.  There may be an element of tradition, or even ritual, to the battles.

The protagonist initially observes a battle from a high vantage point, like the top of a canyon.  The battleground is an open space with walls; it may even be entirely underground.  He sees soldiers attacking, then these massive war machines roll out, there is massive destruction and then, basically, there is nothing left.

He meets someone from one side, and he may even end up in battle himself, but what I remember doesn't go much past the visuals and the overall description of the battle.

I read this at least 30 years ago, but my (current) impression is that it was probably an older story, no later than the 1960s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I answered this as a partial answer to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167013/looking-for-anthology-of-sci-fi-short-stories-subterranean-world-scientists-a/167175#167175) question.

This is [Hidden World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_World_(novel)) [(1957)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?41488) by Stanton A. Coblentz.  It was originally published as a serial [*In Caverns Below*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?186966) in *Wonder Stories*, [March](https://archive.org/details/Wonder_Stories_v06n10_1935-03), [April](https://archive.org/details/Wonder_Stories_v06n11_1935-04) and [May](https://archive.org/details/Wonder_Stories_v06n12_1935-05) 1935.  (Links to issue copies on the Internet Archive.)

My copy is a paperback from [the early 70s](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?586294) with a different cover than the one in the Wikipedia article, with two of the "land battleships" in the background and one of the subterranean ("chalk face") warriors in the foreground. Two subterranean kingdoms endlessly fight each other with huge machines and lightning-based weaponry, causing earthquakes.

The scene you describe is when the protagonist and his friend get lost in a mine, possibly during an earthquake.  They observe one of the battles from a high vantage point and then get separated.  They're each captured by opposite sides (or otherwise make their way to the opposing kingdoms - Wu and Zu).

[image: Front cover showing one giant machine driving over the other with a whitefaced soldier in the foreground]

Comment: And shouldn't the date when it was originally published be mentioned, and a link to online issues as in the other question?

Comment: Well, I'd say I got the cover pretty close after 30 years!  That is obviously a match, thank you!

Comment: @DavidW You're welcome.  I read it back in the mid 70s as a young kid, and the cover made a big impression on me, too!